# Django primary key url issues

Tags: django

I am makeing a simple blog project. In my project, there is one page where there is a list of all the blog posts. If you click on the title of the post you are taken to the post. I used (?P\d+) I the URL path so the user would be directed to the correct post. However, this did not work. Any help would be much appreciated.

all_posts.html

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <h1>Blog Posts</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
 {% for blog_post in object_list %}
 <table class="table table-striped">
   <ul class="list-group">
     <li><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'blog_app:view' pk=blog_post.pk %}">{{ blog_post.post_title }}</a></li>
   </ul>
</table>
 {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

modles.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Blog_Post(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=1000, editable=False, null=True)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, editable=True, blank=False, null=True)
    blog_content = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=False, editable=True, null=True)
    files = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=True, auto_now=True, editable=False)
    likes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
```

urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "blog_app"

urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', views.create_blog_post.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('view/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.view_blog_post.as_view(), name='view'),
    path('all_posts/', views.all_blog_posts.as_view(), name='all'),
    path('delete/<slug:slug>', views.delet_blog_post.as_view(), name='delete')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`path` is for converters like slug, str, int, to work with regex you need `re_path`

you can just redefine it as `"view/<int:pk>/"`

Answer (score 0):

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Blog Posts</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    {% for blog_post in object_list %}
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'blog_app:view' pk=blog_post.pk %}">{{ blog_post.post_title }}</a></li>
    </ul>
    </table>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

i think the problem is in this line

```
 <li><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'blog_app:view' pk=blog_post.pk %}">
```

when you send data in url tag you don't assign it to prametars ,
the right line will be this :

```
     <li><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'blog_app:view' blog_post.pk %}">
```